# Return indices when list stops increasing Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have been trying to return the indices where my lists(arrays) stop increasing.  So far I can only get the index of the first time the list stops increasing and it returns it repeatedly.  With array_1 = np.array([1,2,2,1,1,2,1]) the output should be [2,5] since those are the indices that stop increasing.

```
def monotonic_check(ori_array):
    indices_array = []
    for i in ori_array:
        try:
            if ori_array[i] > ori_array[i+1]:
                indices_array.append(i)
            else:
                continue
        except:
            pass
    return indices_array
```

This code instead is returning [2,2,2]

Comment: For i in range(l'en(array))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the value instead of the index

```
def monotonic_check(ori_array):
    indices_array = []
    for i in range(len(ori_array)):
        try:
            if ori_array[i] > ori_array[i+1]:
                indices_array.append(i)
            else:
                continue
        except:
            pass
    return indices_array
```